# How do I split/format a longer string inside the code?

Tags: javascript

I have an probably simply question, even tho I could not find the answer for it via google or Stackoverflow.

I have a very long string which I want to store in a constant, however it looks awfull in my editor:
[image]

My objective would be to split this longer string into seperate parts inside my code, somehow like this:
[image]

As you see, JS of course does not understand that the line 8-11 should still be part of the string. How can I acomplish that?

Comment: How about using `+`?

Comment: It depends on your IDE, but search google for "<IDE-NAME> word/sentence wrap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the newlines

```js
const str = `asödfjkdaölksdjaskldjasöldkjakldjadlkajsdEND\
BEGINNINGasdöasjkdaöslkdjasködljasdkljasdlkEND\
BEGINNINGasjköaösdjaöklsdjalkdsjaskld`

console.log(str)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! And sorry for bothering with such an easy task to acomplish...

Comment: It is easy if you know how. It is not obvious